# lightning options in SceneKit

Tags: ios, scenekit

SceneKit offers a bunch of light properties. I am unsure what exactly do they do. This is the screenshot from SceneKit Editor. I am looking for ways to optimize my game performance and have come across these properties. Do any of this properties contribute to the performance? Should some be avoided?

[image]

Comment: Go to https://developer.apple.com/scenekit/. You have videos for new Scene Kit in Xcode 7 that goes through new stuff, and scene kit editor is completely new.

Comment: These are general settings, they're not covered in the WWDC videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transparency Mode defines what happens when an object is partially transparent. Here you set Multiply, Additive, Screen, etc modes of calculating what's going to happen as the camera "sees through" the partially transparent object to whatever is behind it. Unfortunately they've chosen to use OpenGL terminology here. So... dunno.

Shininess is another way of saying "Specular Highlights" and is the amount of shine/sparkle you get where light bounces from the source, off the object and directly to the camera. Generally this is sort of like an area*intensity type of thing, but SceneKit has sort of simplified it, stupidly, so you don't really know what it does unless you experiment.

Similarly, Fresnel describes what happens at differing angles of bounce (those that aren't directly from the light source, off the object and into the camera) and this is best used to make metals and glass (and woods and plastic) look more realistic by controlling how the angled light bounces around on the surface, and what this does. It shouldn't be simply one setting, so, again, more testing to find out what it controls.

The lighting model is also about this specular highlight, sort of. These determine the shapes of the highlights, more than anything else.

After that, I'm guessing even more than I am above.

Generally speaking these will all have some effect on performance, but not significant. The worst would be a heavy blend mode, which might double or triple the effort of the GPU over the top of areas with transparency. None of these things will give you a significant jump in performance unless you're somehow right on the verge of being performant, and they make difference sufficient to get you under that.

From what I understand of your previous problems, I think there's something else troubling your use of Scene Kit, likely something about Scene Kit.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest creating your scene, tuning it to your liking, and then create a light map based on that scene.

That would drastically improve performance, assuming you then remove the number of dynamic lights in your scene to 3 maximum.

I watched a WWDC video where the guy said that the number of draw calls to the GPU is multiplied by the number of lights in your scene.